# React child to parent communication

Tags: reactjs

Am new to react developing a page with 3 UI cards like structure each card has 10 to 15 fields. At last has submit button, which will submit the page and summary will display in next page.

so developed 3 components for each card and one main component which will combine 3 components and submit button when a user clicks on submit I want state data of all 3 components how to do this in react.

Can I use a callback or react redux, which is the best implementation. please provide some example.
 Sample Code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

import {store} from '../../index'
import '../../UX-UI-Components/desktop/css/commonUI.css'
import Card1 from './Card1'
import Card2 from './Card2'
import Card3 from './Card3'
import Button from '../../components/Button'
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl'

class Main extends React.Component {

  render() {
     return (
    <div className="">
            <Card1 />
            <Card2 />
            <Card3 />           
            <Link to={'/Summary'}>
            <Button buttonType="primary" onClick = {this.submit} align="right">
                <label><FormattedMessage id="lbl_viewSummary"/></label>
            </Button>
            </Link>
            <Button buttonType="second" align="right">
                <label><FormattedMessage id="lbl-cancel"/></label>
            </Button>
    </div>
     );
  }
}
export default Main
===================================================================================
class Card1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
        d1:"",
        d2: "",
        ......
        d10:""
     }
  };

  render() {
     return (
            <Text onChange={(event) => this.setState({ d1: event.target.value })}>   
            <Text onChange={(event) => this.setState({ d2: event.target.value })}> 
            .....
            <Text onChange={(event) => this.setState({ d10: event.target.value })}>   


     );
  }
}

export default Card1
```

like wise 2 more card classes.. i need all these cards states values in main class

Thank You

Comment: if you are new to react, go for mobx .You will definitely love it

Comment: Can you show your work?

Comment: My our architects suggested react :(

Comment: *"which is the best implementation"* That depends on your specific situation and needs. I'd suggest to start simple and pull in more libraries/abstractions as needed.

Comment: @JustinPearce : u want to see UI  or code

Comment: @user1912935 If you are having problems with code, please post your code.

Comment: i cant post original code but for your understanding sending sample code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your application is going to get much larger than this then redux is definitely the way to go, you should read in to it.

To do this without redux you would need to define all the fields in the state of the parent component and pass methods to the children to update them. So you could do something like this:

#### Parent

```
import Child from './Child';

class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);

       this.state = {
           card_1: {
               field_1: null,
               field_2: null
           },
           card_2: {
               field_1: null,
               field_2: null
           },
           card_3: {
               field_1: null,
               field_2: null
           }
       }
    }

    updateField(card, field, value) {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            [card]: {
                ...this.state[card],
                [field]: value
            }
        });
    }

    handleClick() {
        // Do something with this.state
    }

    render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Child {...this.state} updateField={(card, field, value) => this.updateField(card, field, value)} />
                    <button onClick={() => this.handleClick} />
                </div>
            )
    }
}
```

#### Child

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    render() {
            return (
                <input
                    name="field_1"
                    defaultValue={this.props.card_1.field_1}
                    onChange={(e) => this.props.updateField("card_1", "field_1", e.target.value)}
                />
            )
    }
}
```

This method updates the state in the **Parent** component, so you can then call a method with from an onClick in a button on that component and use the data in the state to process.

## --- Edit ---

To do this using redux I would create a reducer to deal with the form, and an action to update the form data in the state. Something like this:

#### Files

```
-Form.js
-Card.js
-actions.js
-reducer.js
```

#### Form

```
import Card from './Card';
import { initialState } from './reducer';
import { formUpdateField } from './actions';

class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);

       this.state = { ...initialState } // Copy the initial state to our Component state when it loads
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        // Set the props to the component sate
        return this.setState({ ...newProps });
    }

    handleClick() {
        // Do something with this.state
        // Or better still, call to another action to deal with the state in the reducer directly
    }

    render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    // Populate each of the Card components and send the state along with the updateField action and the id for each card
                    <Card cardId='card_1' {...this.state} updateField={(card, field, value) => this.props.updateField(card, field, value)} />
                    <Card cardId='card_2' {...this.state} updateField={(card, field, value) => this.props.updateField(card, field, value)} />
                    <Card cardId='card_3' {...this.state} updateField={(card, field, value) => this.props.updateField(card, field, value)} />

                    // Button to click and use the handle the data in state
                    <button onClick={() => this.handleClick} />
                </div>
            )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  // Return the new state from the reducer to componentWillReceiveProps
  return { ...state.formReducer }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    // Map our actions to this.props using the store dispatch method
    return {
        updateField(card, field, value) => dispatch( formUpdateField(card, field, value) )
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Form);
```

#### Card

```
class Card extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
                   <div>
                       {
                            Object.keys(this.props[ this.props.cardId ]).map(key => {
                                return <input
                                name={ key }
                                defaultValue={ this.props[card_1][key] }
                                onChange={(e) => this.props.updateField(this.props.cardId, key, e.target.value)}
                            />
                        }
                    </div>
                )
    }
}
```

#### actions

```
import store from '../store'; // or wherever your redux store is created

export const formUpdateField = ({ card, field, value }) => {
     let state = store.getState().formReducer;

     // Change field in state
     state = {
         ...state,
         [card]: {
             ...state[card],
             [field]: value
         }
     };

     return {
         type: FORM_UPDATE_FIELD,
         payload: state
     }
}
```

#### reducer

```
export const initialState = {
    card_1: {
        field_1: null,
        field_2: null
    },
    card_2: {
        field_1: null,
        field_2: null
    },
    card_3: {
        field_1: null,
        field_2: null
    }
};

export const FORM_UPDATE_FIELD = 'FORM_UPDATE_FIELD';

export const formReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FORM_UPDATE_FIELD:
            // Return new state from action to component
            return action.payload;

        default:
            // Always return a default state
            return state;
    }
};
```

**Please note that this is pseudo code and untested.**

Here is a good tutorial on using redux with react:
https://www.valentinog.com/blog/react-redux-tutorial-beginners/

I hope this helps.

Comment: So i think using call back is not suggested... if i use redux do i need to dispatch in each fields onchange event.. can you please change above code to redux impl.. thank you...

Comment: I've edited my answer with reference to how you should begin to achieve this with redux. It's well worth you looking in to redux and getting a firm grip of it - it will save you some real headaches when your application grows in size! Also look in to `thunk`, a middleware for redux which allows you to dispatch asynchronous actions - it will also allow you to return `getState` along with dispatch, preventing the need to import it in to each action file.

Comment: Let me know if this works for you, or if you need any help.

Comment: Thanks alot @TPHughes it helped me alot.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad :).